# when there is two straits who win?

Tags: rules

Me and my friends were playing a friendly poker game & we were in this doubt.
my friend Markus had card 4,k & I had card 7,2 & on the deck there was 5,6,7,8,9 in this situation who wins. please explain. thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a chop (a draw). You both get paid equally, because the based 5-card combination is on the board (5 6 7 8 9)